# Dropdown list call back not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I am new in ASP.net developing i have webpage contains two dropdownlist
the first one contains static items 
the second dropdownlist have dynamic value read from database

when i enabled callback = true for first dropdownlist and write the following code

```
Protected Sub zr_dl_select_user_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles zr_dl_select_user.SelectedIndexChanged
    zr_btn_add.Text = zr_dl_select_user.SelectedItem.Value
    zr_tb_fullName.Text = Now().ToString
    Dim db As New mssqldb
    Dim select_sql_stm As String = "SELECT TOP 1 h_id From HOTELS WHERE u_id = @x_uid"
    if(db.reader.read) Then
       zr_dl_group.Items.FindByValue(db.readr("h_id")).Selected = True
    End if
End Sub
```

my page will not respond for any changes and freez out

Comment: What error are you getting? Looking at the code you don't seem to have set up your sql execution correctly.

Comment: yes i do not get any error but the second dropdownlist dose not display the selected value and the button dosenot get the value too
when i remove the zr_dl_group ....
it is work perfectly i do not know why??? this happens

Comment: You should remove asp-classic from your tags as it is not applicable

Comment: Make sure you are only populating the dropdown in your page load when there is no postback.

Answer (score 0):

Make **autopostback** property of *dropdown(zr_dl_select_user)* **true** in **.aspx** page and check.